# Making a list of input variables within a funciton

Tags: python, list, dictionary, local, iterable

I am using the locals function to make a iterable object populated with the values of a,b,c provided when I call this function. When I iterate through the dictionairy that locals returns, I iterate through the variable names, rather than there values. But l.values is not iterable, I guess it points to a function, not a list like I was expecting.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  file.py on line ?, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runaedlz(testInputs[i])
  file.py on line ?, in _runaedlz
    return extraNumber(*_fArgs_dfasruobxant)
  file.py on line 5, in extraNumber
    for i in l:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Is there a better way to make a list of these values? I could do it in a more brute force way, but I'm trying to learn all these built in functions and what they are good for.

Or is there a way to iterate through the dictionairies values that I'm missing?

Two different ways to accomplish the same thing, yes?

```
def extraNumber(a, b, c):
    l=locals()
    l=l.values
    print(l)
    for i in l:
        if(l.count(i)==1):
            return i
```

Comment: try using l.values() instead. seems like values() is a function, so call it.

Comment: WOW, it's amazing sometimes. The difference between l.values and l.values() did the trick.

Comment: cool! sometimes if you're not sure if an attribute hanging off an object is callable, there's a callable(l.values) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def extraNumber(a,b,c):
...     for i in locals().values():
...         yield i
... 
>>> 
>>> for n in extraNumber(5,10,7):
...     n
... 
10
5
7
```

I've used a **yield** statement because the **extraNumber** function will produce one value for each argument value.

As an alternative, if you want the entire list at once you could use something like this.

```
>>> def extraNumber(a,b,c):
...     parameterValues=list(locals().values())
...     return parameterValues
...     
>>> extraNumber(5,10,7)
[10, 5, 7]
```

Comment: I've never seen yield before now. That could come in handy. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, generating is the ilst is what I am after, but I may have to play with your other examples, just to familiarize myself with different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

A potential problem with `locals()` is that it returns a dictionary, and the order of values in a dictionary isn't defined, hence listing the values might permute them relative to the order in which they were passed to the function. If you really want to do something like this, you can get the order defined by using the function's `__code__` object's `__co_varnames` attribute. Something like:

```
def extraNumber(a, b, c):
    loc = locals() #should be the first line, so that only parameters have values
    vals = list(loc.values()) #order might have been changed
    lvals = extraNumber.__code__.co_varnames
    orderedVals = [loc[x] for x in lvals if x in loc]
    return vals, orderedVals #both returned for comparison
```

When I ran it I got:

```
>>> extraNumber(1,2,3)
([3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3])
```

Different runs (especially in fresh Python shells) will have different orders in the first returned list, but the second will always be `[1,2,3]`